# Can I use [[__progmem__]] instead of PROGMEM?

Tags: progmem

In `pgmspace.h`, `PROGMEM` is defined as `__ATTR_PROGMEM__`, which is defined as `__attribute__((__progmem__))`. AFAIK, `__attribute__` is GNU only. Since C++ 11, we have the [attribute specifier sequence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes).

I can't use `[[__progmem__]]` instead of `PROGMEM`. The error is

> warning: '__progmem__' attribute directive ignored [-Wattributes]

Shouldn't that work equally?

Why would I want to do that?

1. **Clarity**: When I first read code that used PROGMEM, I thought that this is the variable name (being a constant, we have a conding guideline that it should be upper case, which matched). Reading on, I found the real variable name, which confused me. Putting it into square brackets would immediately have made clear that it's an attribute and not a name.
2. **Portability**: `[[ ]]` is Standard C++, whereas `__attribute__` is not.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I should just read the complete documentation...

Under [Standard Attributes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes#Standard_attributes), we see the attributes that come with the C++ Standard. `__progmem__` isn't one of them.

Following the example for syntax 2, I tried `[[gnu::__progmem__]]`, which compiles. So this helps with *Clarity*, but since it now has the `gnu` namespace, it doesn't help with *Portability*.

Comment: Re “it doesn't help with _Portability_”: According to the [documentation of `PROGMEM`](https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__pgmspace.html), “These functions are an attempt to provide some compatibility with header files that come with IAR C, to make porting applications between different compilers easier.” I doubt `PROGMEM` could be a lot more portable than that. How many C compilers (let alone C++) support the AVR architecture? How many of those support keeping constants in flash memory?

Comment: And the macro approach has the nice effect that you can provide a macro without replacement text for systems that do not support such attributes, for example if you simulate on a PC.